# Loading a jsp forwarded from servlet in parent window instead of loading in popup window

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am creating a pop up window through jsp and passing some selected values in pop up window to jsp. while doing this i am using servlet ie. from pop up window i am calling servlet and in servlet i am using request dispacher and forwarding the result to jsp. this whole process is working fine, but the new jsp  to which it is forwarded from servlet is loaded in the same popup window
but i need to load this jsp in parent window.Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your popup window call `parent.document.location='youservletname'` and close popup window (`window.close()`).